# Why is my div background separated around the header?

Tags: html, css

I have most of my code in a div so that I can then have a separate background color for it against the main page background. I'm essentially trying to recreate this page: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/VPaoNP

However, for some reason, the div background color spreads to around the header as well, even though my header isn't in the div and there's no div with the same name above the header in the html. Any help as to why this is happening?
Here's a link to mine to see exactly what I mean: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/MJjpwO?editors=1100

I expect the background color #fcfcfc to only be in the div, not also above the header. It's actually creating two separate sections with that background color, the div area and a blank area above the header.

```css
#title{
          text-align: center;
         }
        #description{
          text-align: center;
        }

        #name-label{
           display: inline-block;
          width: 25%;
          text-align: right;
        }
        #name {
          width: 50%;
          padding: 8px 8px;
          margin: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: none;
          display: inline-block;
          float: center;
        }
        #email-label{
           display: inline-block;
          width: 25%;
          text-align: right;
        }
        #email {
           width: 50%;
          padding: 8px 8px;
          margin: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: none;
          display: inline-block;
          float: center;
        }
        #number-label{
          display: inline-block;
          width: 25%;
          text-align: right;
        }
        #number{
           width: 50%;
          padding: 8px 8px;
          margin: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: none;
          display: inline-block;
          float: center;
        }
        body {
          background: #d9f5fc;
          font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
        }
        div {
          background: #fcfcfc;
          padding: 40px;
          width: 800px;
          margin: auto;
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

    <html>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">

    <body>
      <h1 id="title"> Survey Form</h1>
      <div id="form">
        <p id="description"> Let us know how we can better help you!</p>
        <form id="survey-form">

          <label for id="name-label">*Name:</label>
          <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
          <br>
          <label for id="email-label">*Email:</label>
          <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
          <br>
          <label for id="number-label">*Age:</label>
          <input id="number" type="number" min="15" max="110" name="age" placeholder="Enter your age" required>
          <br>
          Which option best describes your current employment?
          <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="student">Student</option>
            <option value="full time employement">Full Time Employment</option>
            <option value="part time employment">Part Time Employment</option>
            <option value="secret">It's a Secret...</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>


          *How likely is it that you would recommend us to a friend? 
             <id="recommend">
          <input id="very" type="radio" name="likelyhood" value="Very">
            <label for="very">Very</label>
            <br>
          <input type="radio" name="likelyhood" value="Somewhat">
            <label for="somewhat">Somewhat</label> 
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="likelyhood" value="Not Very"> 
            <label for="notvery">Not Very</label>


          <br>
          What do you like most about our site?
          <select id="dropdown2">
                  <option value="navigation">Navigation</option>
                  <option value="colorscheme">Color Scheme</option>
                  <option value="options">Options Offered</option>
                  <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          Things that you'd like to see Improved in the Future (Check all that Apply):
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="sizes">More Sizes <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="styles">More Styles <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="colors">More Colors <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="helptime">Quicker Help Response Time <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="quality">Better Quality <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="improvements" value="sustainability">Improved Sustainability <br>
          <br>
          Any Comments or Suggestions? Let us know! 
          <textarea rows="5" cols="40"> Enter your comments here...
          </textarea>
          <br>
          <input id="submit" type="submit"
          </form>
               </div>

    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry which header? it doesn't seem to be doing that for me

Comment: i dont get what you want to do

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimal amount to replicate the problem. There is a lot of code there that is not relevant. Please see [MCVE]

Comment: @JonP I wanted to include all of the code because I wasn't sure what was causing the problem.

Comment: You'll get there, an important part of debugging is reducing the problem to the smallest possible example. This gets easier the more you do it. For example everything in your `form` tag should not be part of the problem, remove that...see if you still have the issue, then repeat with other elements. Reducing the size of the haystack makes it easier to find the needle. Also get familiar with browser developer tools (f12 in most browsers), that will enable you to see what styles are applied to elements on the page. That will also help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @cyrus I want to remove the light blue above the header that says Survey Form. I don't know why it's there to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the header that's considered a div. Where you added the script tag (the one with the freecodecamp src), it inserted a div into your code. Since the div they inserted had no width or height except for the 3 lines on the side, your text went over it. But when you gave the div a background color and width/padding, it affected both your div and the freecodecamp div. The simple solution is to change the `div` from the css to `#form`.

```
div {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Basically, since they had a div, , the background you have applies to both their div and your div. Give the div a class, or use the existing id (`form`), and only apply the background to that.

Comment: I ended up using the form id and applying the background to just that, like you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome! One of the first steps of debugging is to remove parts of your code one at a time, and then try to figure out the problem with that. Debugging is an important skill.

Also, as a general rule, I suggest you never use the tag name as your class (div, p, h1). The tag `<a>` is an exception, but generally, give it a class name or id and apply your css to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I changed to make your page work as desired:

Remove `<html>` from the code (below). The `<html>` tag should go directly beneath your `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag on the very first line of your page (or output).

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <html>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
```

Add `</head>` before the `<body>` tag:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">
</head>    
<body>
```

Close your `</body>` tag at the bottom of the page:

```
  </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Essential html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang-"en"> 
<head>
 ... title, scripts, css/links, meta tags
</head>
<body>
 ... page content
</body>
</html>
```